# Ubuntu 20.04 won't load. It's stuck at /dev/sda5: clean xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks

Tags: 20.04

After removing some drivers / packages Ubuntu 20.04 is not loading any more.
Following commands were executed:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge radeon*
sudo apt --purge autoremove
```

It stops loading at the following message:

```
/dev/sda5: clean xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks
```

underscore indicator is blinking but desktop UI is not loading. I've tried following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

it didn't help. Is there any way to fix the UI load without uninstalling the entire OS?

It is possible to boot in the rescue mode and login to Ubuntu, so that I still can login and access the OS through the command line.

PS. I do have enough space on the disk.

Comment: FYI:  I don't see anything related to drive error; the `fsck` message is more likely because the OP has **not** cleanly rebooted their machine (eg. didn't use SysRq commands to direct kernel to safely reboot; instead possibly used the power-off thus forced *unclean* off & creating *file-system* issues that caused file-system check; it's a *logical* error not actual *drive* error) @David.  Semen; being specific about what you did remove though would help us to help you.  You can use *live* media to access your files.

Comment: @David I removed all packages related to the radeon video card and I also run following command: `sudo apt-get remove --purge radeon*` and after that I did `sudo apt --purge autoremove`

Comment: @guiverc I still can login to the Ubuntu OS using Resque mode via command line. It's only UI that won't load.

Comment: editing and updating the question not just giving more info in comments is a good idea.

Comment: Following from @guiverc 's comment above, the problem is not that message, the problem is the graphical desktop not loading and the reason for that is because you removed the graphical driver `radeon`. WHY? What problem were you trying to solve? Whatever that was the solution certainly isn't to uninstall the only driver that works.